# Get value from document element in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I am creating frontend for my SpringBoot application. To send a Get request I need to get the value from input in my program, but have no success.

I've tried to use any king of `.value`, `valueOf()`, `.toString()` methods after selecting `document.getElementById("name")` and non of them seem to work.

// the element

```
<form class="pt-3">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for ="name">Person ID</label>
      <input
         type="text"
         id="name"
         class="form-control is"
         :class="{'is-invalid': $v.name.$error} "
         @input="$v.name.$touch()"
         v-model="name"
         placeholder="123456"
         value=""
      >
      <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.name.minLength">ID must be at least 5 characters</div>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" @click="FetchData">Найти</button>
   </div>  
</form>
```

// the function

```
AddPerson: function () {
    var nperson = document.getElementById("name").valueOf().value.name;
    console.log(nperson);
}
```

I need to output the text the user inputs into the name line on the page and post it to `console.log()`.

/// Added

```
data() {
  return {
    result: '',
    name: '',
    seats: '',
    reservation: ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're binding the input value to `name` property using `v-model` you could use that property directly inside your method as follows:

```
 AddPerson: function () {
     var nperson = this.name;
   console.log(nperson);
 }
```

and `name` property should be defined inside your data object like :

```
 data(){
    return{
          name:'',
          ...
        }
     }
```

and try `text` as input type instead of `name` :

```
<input type="text" ...
```

**Full example**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      result: '',
      name: '',
      seats: '',
      reservation: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    FetchData() {
      var nperson = this.name
      console.log(nperson);
    
  },
  AddPerson: function() {
    var nperson = this.name
    console.log(nperson);
  }

}
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">
  <form class="pt-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Person ID</label>
      <input type="name" id="name" class="form-control is" @input="AddPerson" v-model="name" placeholder="123456" value="">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">ID must be at least 5 characters</div>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" @click.prevent="FetchData">Найти</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use this.name i get nothing in the output although a input "123" in the textbox

Comment: This is 100% the expected way this should be done.  The whole point of Vue and other MVC frameworks is that you should NEVER be touching the document directly unless the framework is missing a key feature.

Comment: @Paul could you provide your data object?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have added the description

Comment: The problem didn't go away after I tried to fix it using you comment. Do you have any more ideas to why i seem to get it?

Comment: @Paul i updated my answer by adding a running code snippet

Comment: Your last edit seems to work
<input type="name" id="name" class="form-control is" @input="AddPerson" v-model="name" placeholder="123456" value="">
How can I make it so the AddPerson function doesn't get called every time i add a letter, but rather when i push a button?

Comment: @Paul thanks for accepting my answer  and to avoid the function call every time you type a letter you should just remove `@input="AddPerson"`

Answer (score 1):

This should work well, the whole point of Vue is so you don't have to work directly with the DOM.  Simply use the `name` variable either through your vue instance (`vm` in this case) or through `this`.  Remember that arrow functions capture the current scope and therefore you can't use `this` correctly within them, be sure you're using `function() ...` definitions for your methods.

I trimmed a lot of the fat from the example but it'll all still work with it in your final product. I just didn't want to replicate your whole project for a small demo.

```js
let vm = new Vue({
  el : "#root",
  data : {
    name : "hi"
  },
  methods : {
    FetchData : function(e) {
      console.log(this.name);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<form id="root" class="pt-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for ="name">Person ID</label>
    <input
      id="name"
      v-model="name"
      placeholder="123456"
    >
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!name.minLength">ID должн быть минимум 5 символов</div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" @click="FetchData">Найти</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin a cat - the standard vuejs one would be through `v-model`, one other using `$refs` and - don't forget - vanilla JS is allways there for you as well with `document.getElementById('id-name').value`. I demonstrate all three ways in this example:

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/Hexodus/pen/MWydpxW)

Template:

```
  <template>
    <div id="app">
      <h5>Tree ways to get your input value</h5>
      <div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Person ID</label>
            <input
               type="text"
               id="myName"
               ref="myInput"
               v-model="name"
               placeholder="123456"
            >
            <div class="spacer">
              <button @click="outputFromModel">v-model</button>
             <button @click="outputFromRef">ref</button>
             <button @click="outputFromId">ID</button>
           </div>
         </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

JS:

```
  <script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        name: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      outputFromModel() {
        alert(this.name)
      },
     outputFromRef() {
        alert(this.$refs.myInput.value)
      },
      outputFromId() {
        alert(document.getElementById('myName').value)
      },
    }
  };
  </script>
```